# Why doesn't the accumulator in my reduce function take on the callback's return value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming

I have an array of objects and I want to sum all the "bps" values in my object for the entire array.

**My array of objects looks like this:**

```
arr = [
    {
        date: "2017-06-14T14:00:00.000Z",
        bps: 2
    },
    ...
]
```

**Here is my reduce function:**

```
arr.reduce((accum, currVal) => {
        console.log(accum.bps);
        console.log(currVal.bps);
        console.log(accum.bps + currVal.bps);
        return accum.bps + currVal.bps;
    }, {
        bps: 0
    });
```

Based on what has been outputted to the console, it appears that after the first iteration of the reduce function, the return value of 0 does not become the next iteration's accumulator (it becomes "undefined"). Why is this the case and what should my function look like to sum up all the "bps" values in my array?

**The is what the console is displaying**

```
scripts.js:1024 0
scripts.js:1025 0
scripts.js:1026 0
scripts.js:1024 undefined
scripts.js:1025 0
scripts.js:1026 NaN
scripts.js:1024 undefined
scripts.js:1025 0
scripts.js:1026 NaN
scripts.js:1024 undefined
scripts.js:1025 0
scripts.js:1026 NaN
scripts.js:1024 undefined
scripts.js:1025 0
scripts.js:1026 NaN
scripts.js:1024 undefined
scripts.js:1025 0
scripts.js:1026 NaN
scripts.js:1024 undefined
scripts.js:1025 0
scripts.js:1026 NaN
scripts.js:1024 undefined
scripts.js:1025 0
scripts.js:1026 NaN
scripts.js:1024 undefined
scripts.js:1025 0
scripts.js:1026 NaN
scripts.js:1024 undefined
scripts.js:1025 0
scripts.js:1026 NaN
scripts.js:1024 undefined
scripts.js:1025 0
scripts.js:1026 NaN
scripts.js:1024 undefined
scripts.js:1025 1.95
scripts.js:1026 NaN
scripts.js:1024 undefined
scripts.js:1025 0
scripts.js:1026 NaN
scripts.js:1024 undefined
scripts.js:1025 0
scripts.js:1026 NaN
scripts.js:1031 NaN
```

Comment: `return accum.bps + currVal.bps` returns a number ... which has no property named `bps`

Comment: try `arr.map(({bps}) => bps).reduce((a, b) => a + b);`

Comment: I see it now. Thanks for the clarification - it's working fine now.

Comment: Also possible with lodash `_.sumBy(arr, elem => elem.bps)`

Comment: Thanks fredrik.hjamer. I actually started using lodash today so I will look into getting rid of the function I wrote myself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your reduce is simply adding all the `.bps` values together, you can simply map all the array items to an array of numbers, then add those together

```
arr.map(({bps}) => bps)
.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

or even

```
arr.reduce((accum, {bps}) => accum + bps, 0);
```

Comment: This answer is better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

You should return an object that has a `bps` key, not a pure sum.

I.e. `return { bps: accum.bps + currVal.bps };` instead of `return accum.bps + currVal.bps;`

---

```
arr
  .reduce((accum, currVal) => {
    console.log(accum.bps);
    console.log(currVal.bps);
    console.log(accum.bps + currVal.bps);
    return { bps: accum.bps + currVal.bps };
  }, {
    bps: 0
  })
  .bps;
```

---

<strike>**Alternatively** (this will actually work faster, especially for long arrays, because it doesn't create unnecessary objects, only the result object).</strike>

```
const bpsResult = {
  bps:
    arr
      .reduce((accum, currVal) => {
        console.log(accum);
        console.log(currVal);
        console.log(accum + currVal);
        return accum + currVal;
    },
    0);
  };
```

Comment: not sure about that second bit of code! currVal will be an object, wont it?

Comment: The alternative solution only works if the contents of `arr` are different though, or you do a preprocessing `map` to extract the `bps` values.

Comment: Oh, no! You guys are right! @ShadowRanger I didn't notice the second field on the object in array!

Answer (score 0):

This works.  accum is a number so don't use accum.bps.  Also, the initial value is a number, so don't use {bps: 0}, just use 0.

```
arr = [{
    date: "2017-06-14T14:00:00.000Z",
    bps: 2
}, {
    date: "2017-05-14T14:00:00.000Z",
    bps: 9
}, {
    date: "2017-08-14T14:00:00.000Z",
    bps: 4
}]

// Here is my reduce function:

arr.reduce((accum, currVal) => {
    console.log("accum-" + accum);
    console.log("currVal.bps-" + currVal.bps);
    console.log("return value-" + (accum + currVal.bps));
    return accum + currVal.bps;
}, 0);
```

Here is the output:

```
accum-0
currVal.bps-2
return value-2
accum-2
currVal.bps-9
return value-11
accum-11
currVal.bps-4
return value-15
```